# Export/download answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to download answers that are helpful or offer brilliant solutions/demonstrations of the power of LaTeX?

For example I particularly like the following:

[Clickable chapters on the right side of each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181081/clickable-chapters-on-the-right-side-of-each-page)

[Milestone graphic in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159835/milestone-graphic-in-tikz/159856#comment365349_159856)

I know some people will say "*why not cut and paste the code, duh*" but often it is very helpful to see the thread and the comments also, as there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Maybe a download thread/solution button...

**EDIT following Torbjorn T's comment**

I suppose this shall now be bumped up to be a Feature Request. Can the "Print" feature as in http://www.stackprinter.com (or something similar, license issues notwithstanding) be added to the q/a thread on tex.SE.

Comment: Something like http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/825?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Cool, thanks for the link. I have changed the emphasis of my question to be a feature request.

Comment: Also see [Printable version of questions/answers or entire discussion](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1680/5764)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that this will eventually get marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). The primary purpose of SE is to provide online support. If you find some Q&A very useful, you can star them (= put them into your favourites). I doubt the team will spend time on this feature, especially since SE provides an API and many apps for thread downloading exist out there (i.e. on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com)).